# Vue.js router-link $route.params display image

Tags: api, vue.js, parameters, axios

```
 <div class="card" v-for="job in filteredJobs" :key="job.id">
    <router-link
      :to="{
        name: 'JobDetails',
        params: {
          id: job.id,
          title: job.title,
          type: job.type,
          company: job.company,
          company_url: job.company_url,
          created_at: job.created_at,
          location: job.location,
          description: job.description,
          company_logo: job.company_logo,
        },
      }"
    >
```

Next Page:

```
div class="card companyCard">
    <img 
    height="50px"
    width="50px"
    src="$route.params.company_logo"
    alt="company Logo"/>
    <h5>{{ $route.params.company }}</h5>
```

Is it possible to set the image src to $route.params somehow? Or do i need to find a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the image is hosted online you could just add `:` to the src attribute :

```
:src="$route.params.company_logo"
```

if the images is in the add require :

```
:src="require($route.params.company_logo)"
```